# navigation stack within child view controller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, childviewcontroller

I am putting a `UINavigationController` inside a container view like so (this in a full screen `UIViewController` subclass):

```
  UIViewController *litteViewController = [[UIViewController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
  UINavigationController *littleNavigator = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:litteViewController];

  UIView *containerView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100.0, 100.0, 250.0, 320.0)];
  littleNavigator.view.frame = containerView.bounds;

  [self addChildViewController:littleNavigator];

  [containerView addSubview:littleNavigator.view];
  [self.view addSubview:containerView];

  [littleNavigator didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Now this works as expected and `littleViewController` appears in the rect I expect with a nav bar at top.  Now let us say as a result of some interaction inside `littleViewController` something like this happens

```
 -(void)someButtonAction:(id)sender{

       UIViewController *secondLittleViewController = [[UIViewController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
       [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:secondLittleViewController animated:YES];
}
```

unfortunately this subsequent controller winds up being presented full screen.  Now I've done exactly this before inside `popoverControllers` and `splitViewControllers` and they've behaved exactly as I want this to, a navigation stack is built within the little rectangle it was started in.

How can I build a navigation stack inside a container over in an arbitrary CGRect?

Comment: iPhone or iPad? iOS version?

Comment: thanks mate.  the code I'm looking for should work on any iOs device >= iOs5 (which is where the addChildViewConroller: stuff is)

Comment: On iPhone and iPod touch, the presented view is always full screen. So you need change to pushViewController

Comment: Oh yeah! wow thanks can't believe i forgot that one. thanks so much make it an answer will you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On iPhone and iPod touch, the presented view is always full screen. So you need change to pushViewController

Glad I can help

Comment: YEP!!  thanks mate.  pushViewController: animated: has been there forever and i don't think Ive ever really needed it.  Thanks so much